# Expanding solution of linear equations with Cholesky factors to matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, cholesky-decomposition

Suppose $B$ is $N\times N$ matrix and $A$ is $N\times M$ matrix.
$A$ and $B$ is given, and Cholesky factor $L$ is also given which satisfy $B=LL^T$.

My question is how to calculate $B^{-1}A$ efficiently.

I know if $A$ was a vector, we could solve it with $O(N^2)$ by backward substitution method.
Is there faster way than simply repeating backward substitution method $M$ times (this results in $O(N^2M$))?

Comment: How can $B$ be not given if $L$ is known and $B =LL^{T}$?

Comment: >François Diderot, sorry $B$ was given. I edit the post.

Comment: $O(N^2)$, is the fastest way to find the inverse of a matrix up till now, but it doesn't indeed that is the fastest way to solve the linear system, so what this system represent ?, $B^{-1} A$

Comment: Algorithms such `BFGS` and `LBFGS` usually works, for large $N$.